# tcp://localhost:3000:5000 (URI::InvalidURIError) when running in Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, procfile

Using:

    `ruby "2.4.0"
    gem "rails", "5.1.0.rc1"
    gem "pg", "0.18.4" # postgresql database
    gem foreman
    gem "webpacker", git: "https://github.com/rails/webpacker"`

when I run,

`bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev`
 
which contains these 3 lines:

```
rails: bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
webpack-dev-server: bin/webpack-dev-server
memcached: memcached
```

here is contents of rails s

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands
```

here is contents of webpack-dev-server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$stdout.sync = true

require "shellwords"
require "yaml"

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "development"
RAILS_ENV = ENV["RAILS_ENV"]

ENV["NODE_ENV"] ||= RAILS_ENV
NODE_ENV = ENV["NODE_ENV"]

APP_PATH    = File.expand_path("../", __dir__)
CONFIG_PATH = File.join(APP_PATH, "config/webpack/paths.yml")

begin
  paths = YAML.load(File.read(CONFIG_PATH))[NODE_ENV]

  NODE_MODULES_PATH   = File.join(APP_PATH.shellescape, paths["node_modules"])
  WEBPACK_CONFIG_PATH = File.join(APP_PATH.shellescape, paths["config"])

  WEBPACK_BIN       = "#{NODE_MODULES_PATH}/.bin/webpack-dev-server"
  DEV_SERVER_CONFIG = "#{WEBPACK_CONFIG_PATH}/development.server.js"
rescue Errno::ENOENT, NoMethodError
  puts "Configuration not found in config/webpacker/paths.yml."
  puts "Please run bundle exec rails webpacker:install to install webpacker"
  exit!
end

Dir.chdir(APP_PATH) do
  exec "NODE_PATH=#{NODE_MODULES_PATH} #{WEBPACK_BIN} --progress --color " \
    "--config #{DEV_SERVER_CONFIG}"
end
```

I get this error:

`bundler: failed to load command: foreman (/Users/annie/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/foreman)`

in the detail, i can also see this and not sure how to fix

`bad URI(is not URI?): tcp://localhost:3000:5000 (URI::InvalidURIError)`

If I run the 2 commands that are in the Procfile separately (bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0 & bin/webpack-dev-server) in different Terminals, it all works (no errors)

What is causing the 3000:5000?

How do i fix?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there isn't an ENV variable called `HOST` being set somewhere. I had the same problem using the gem **dotenv-rails**. There was a line in my **.env** file:

`HOST=localhost:3000`

I got rid of that line and foreman worked again.